# Help needed on problem with image on uibutton in uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to create a button in each tableviewcell and upon selected, the "Checked.png" should appear on the button.The default is "uncheck.png". However, the problem is the image always remain in "uncheck.png" regardless of the button being selected. It's driving me mad. Please help me on this. Would greatly appreciate if someone could provide some code snippets.Thank You

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

           UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil) {

               [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableCell" owner:self options:NULL];
               cell = nibLoadedCell;
               UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(270.0, 10.0, 60.0, 60.0)];
              [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
              [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(Selected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
             button.tag = indexPath.row;
             [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
            }
```

Comment: I would suggest replaced the object type of your `UIButton` to a `UIImageView`.  I have been having the same problems trying to swap out images on `UIButtons` which are inside `UITableViewCells`.

Maybe then, place a transparent custom `UIButton` on top of each `UIImageView` that will determine the image of the image view.

Setting the image of a `UIImageView` is much more straightforward

Answer (score 0):

Look at the TouchCells example in XCode. Go to Help -> Developer Documenation and search TouchCells. Have a look at that sample project in XCode

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation

For many controls, UIControlStateSelected state has no effect on behavior or appearance.

I think the same for UIButton also.

What I would suggest is you can set the button setImage property again to Checked.png in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate of tableview.You should also set a unique tag for each button for identifying the button which you have to set the Checked.png Image.